# Does Docker-Compose Down Restart Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Will I notice any interruption in service from my server when I use commands below?

docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d

Comment: what do you mean by any interruption in service ?

Comment: I am running an icecast stream, will the music be interrupted?

Comment: Definitely interrupted because **down** command remove all containers which defined in Compose file

Answer (score 1):

**docker-compose down** stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by **docker-compose up**.

By default, the only things removed are:

```
Containers for services defined in the Compose file
Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file
The default network, if one is used
```

Check here for more https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

Comment: `docker-compose down` won't remove volumes and images. To remove volumes: `docker-compose down -v`